How can I insert one range into another?
I would like to ask how to insert i2 into i1 under the condition below.
It can print numbers sequentially from 0 to A. But i got little problem, about facing an issue where it only prints the number A repeatedly. Is there any way to fix this?
Image:

Left: result i want.
Right: result i got.
Image
    for i2 in range(record_len_id+1): #0 ~ A
        name = i2
        print(name)
    for i1 in range(num_records): ##0 ~ B
        name1 = i1 
        
        this_record = read_data(binary_data, record_len, data_start_point + i1 * record_len)
        MergeFull = ""    
        if read_int(this_record, 0) == 417:
            MergeFull = "======\n{}\n".format(i2) #Condition Here!!!!!!
        MergeFull += "Debug2: {} | ".format(read_int(this_record, 4)) 
        output_file.write(str(MergeFull)+"\n")


just use one loop and increment manually your i2 counter

After the first for loop has finished looping over all its items, the variable i2 will have the value it received in the last iteration of the loop. It's unclear what you want to happen.

thanks for the tip diggusbickus. Sorry for bad question i'm beginning programming

You want something that gives you the current value of an incrementing i2?

When a variable is declared at the top of a for-loop it remains in scope after the for-loop is finished.
When you enter the second for-loop, the variable i2 exists but its value is unchanging (and equal to the value of record_len_id at the start).
Like DiggusBickus suggests, i2 should not be declared in a for-loop but should be updated after each use.
    i2 = 0  # initial value here
    for i1 in range(num_records):
        name1 = i1 
        
        this_record = read_data(binary_data, record_len, data_start_point + i1 * record_len)
        output_line = ""    
        if read_int(this_record, 0) == 417:
            output_line = "======\n{}\n".format(i2)
            i2 += 1  # incremented after use in string
        output_line += "Debug2: {} | ".format(read_int(this_record, 4)) 
        output_file.write(str(output_line)+"\n")

The scope of variables declared in for-loops varies between languages:

For C++, such variables used to remain in scope after exiting the for-loop but twenty years ago the standard was changed so that they go out of scope. This meant that C++ code from the 1990s could get compilation errors after exiting for-loops, if using a new compiler in the late 2000s.
For Java, such variables go out of scope.
For Javascript, whether the variable is in scope depends on which type of for-loop you use. In the simple examples they remain, but not so much for the ranged loops.
For C#, behaviour differs between for and foreach and also between C# versions.

